# Multiple rows of floating table headers

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using this script to float my table headers:
http://cmcqueen1975.bitbucket.org/htmlFloatingTableHeader/tables.html

It is working great for my project, however one of my tables have 2 rows of headers, but it only floats the top one. Is there an easy way to have it float all the rows?

Comment: The biggest issue is it's only querying for the first table row `tr:first` rather than cloning the entire table header `thead` as it should.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for something like this:

```
<table style="position:fixed; top:0;">
    <tr>
       <td>Header1</td>
       <td Header2</td>
       .....
    </tr>
</table>

<table>
   <tr>
      <td>Data1</td>
      <td>Data2</td>
      ....
   </tr>
   .... more rows ...
</table>
```

What this is doing is anchoring the headers to the top of the screen, but will allow the other table to scroll as usual. You may have to do some z-indexing depening on what else is going on on your page.

Comment: I tried that, and temp disabled the other code. And I see 2 problems. First, it's not staying on the top of the screen. It is scrolling off the screen. I'm currently running firefox 15.0. Second, by breaking the headers off from the data, it would break the auto-sizing.

Comment: @YungBlood Sorry it should have been fixed. not absolute. Let me look into the auto-sizing issue.

Comment: So you could definitely do the proper sizing thing with some Javascript, but I am not sure if that is an option for you. In terms of getting with you want with pure css/html so far I have not had any luck.

Comment: Javascript isn't an issue. I'm already using some. You can see that the code I'm using now has javascript, but it only freezes one row. I just don't know understand it's working, so I can't make it freeze multiple rows.

Comment: @YungBlood Well if you are willing to script, get the width of the <td> elements, and then apply those to the header elements. Now they are the same size and they float up top. With way less code than what you have there.

Comment: I've been playing with it, and it still isn't working well for me. I've got an idea, but I'm not quite sure how to implement it. I could create use php to duplicate the entire <thead>, and have it make one copy fixed. But how would I adjust the width to be the same as the auto-width?

Comment: Add the css to the markup dynamically on document load, after you have already measured out the current dimensions of the table.